# RuntimeError: memory access out of bounds Error in Discord.JS hosted on Digital Ocean

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, out-of-memory, digital-ocean

I have coded a Discord Music bot using the distube library which was working properly and wasn't showing this error on local host or heroku but when i shifted to digital ocean, it was initially working smoothly but after some time i started receiving errors related to `wasm-function` and `RuntimeError: memory access out of bounds`. I have added screenshot and code of the error below and have also provided the code which i have written for this bot. I barely have any knowledge about wasm functions and memory access out of bounds error so if someone can help me out with this would be of great help.

**Discord Bot Code**

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs');
const {
  AutoPoster
} = require('topgg-autoposter')
const DisTube = require('distube'),
  config = {
    prefix: "b.",
  };


AutoPoster("Top.gg TOKEN", client)
  .on('posted', () => {
    console.log('Posted stats to Top.gg!')
  })

const distube = new DisTube(client, {
  searchSongs: true,
  emitNewSongOnly: true
});

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on("message", async(message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;
  const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift();

  if (command == "play")
    if (!message.member.voice.channel) {
      message.channel.send("You are not in a voice channel.")
    }
  if (message.member.voice.channel) {
    distube.play(message, args.join(" "));
  }



  if (command == "loop" || command == "repeat") {
    if (!message.member.voice.channel) {
      message.channel.send("You are not in a voice channel.")
    }
    if (message.member.voice.channel) {
      let queue = distube.getQueue(message);
      if (!queue) return message.channel.send("There is no queue.")
      distube.setRepeatMode(message, parseInt(args[0]));
      const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#9966CC')
        .setTitle('Current Song has been Looped!')

      message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
    }

  }

  if (command == "stop") {
    if (!message.member.voice.channel) {
      message.channel.send("You are not in a voice channel.")
    }
    if (message.member.voice.channel) {
      let queue = distube.getQueue(message);
      if (!queue) return message.channel.send("There is no queue.")
      distube.stop(message);
      const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#9966CC')
        .setTitle('Bot has left the voice channel!')

      message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
    }

  }
  if (command == "skip") {
    if (!message.member.voice.channel) {
      message.channel.send("You are not in a voice channel.")
    }
    if (message.member.voice.channel) {
      distube.skip(message);
      let queue = distube.getQueue(message);
      if (!queue) return message.channel.send("There is no queue.")
      const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#9966CC')
        .setTitle('Song has been skipped!')

      message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
    }

  }



  if (command == "volume") {
    if (!message.member.voice.channel) {
      message.channel.send("You are not in a voice channel.")
    }
    if (message.member.voice.channel) {
      let queue = distube.getQueue(message);
      if (!queue) return message.channel.send("There is no queue.")
      distube.setVolume(message, args[0]);
      const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#9966CC')
        .setTitle(`Volume has been set to ${args[0]}% `)

      message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
    }

  }

  if (command == "jump") {
    if (!message.member.voice.channel) {
      message.channel.send("You are not in a voice channel.")
    }
    if (message.member.voice.channel) {
      let queue = distube.getQueue(message);
      if (!queue) return message.channel.send("There is no queue.")
      distube.jump(message, parseInt(args[0] - 1));
    }

  }


  if (command == "shuffle") {
    if (!message.member.voice.channel) {
      message.channel.send("You are not in a voice channel.")
    }
    if (message.member.voice.channel) {
      let queue = distube.getQueue(message);
      if (!queue) return message.channel.send("There is no queue.")
      distube.shuffle(message);
      const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#9966CC')
        .setTitle(`Queue has been shuffled!`)

      message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
    }

  }

  if (command == "pause") {
    if (!message.member.voice.channel) {
      message.channel.send("You are not in a voice channel.")
    }
    if (message.member.voice.channel) {
      let queue = distube.getQueue(message);
      if (!queue) return message.channel.send("There is no queue.")
      distube.pause(message);
      const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#9966CC')
        .setTitle(`Current Song has been paused!`)

      message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
    }

  }


  if (command == "resume") {
    if (!message.member.voice.channel) {
      message.channel.send("You are not in a voice channel.")
    }
    if (message.member.voice.channel) {
      let queue = distube.getQueue(message);
      if (!queue) return message.channel.send("There is no queue.")
      distube.resume(message);
      const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#9966CC')
        .setTitle(`Current Song has been resumed!`)

      message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
    }

  }

  if (command == "queue") {
    let queue = distube.getQueue(message);
    if (!queue) return message.channel.send("There is no queue.")
    const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#9966CC')
      .setTitle('Current Queue')
      .setDescription(queue.songs.map((song, id) =>
        `**${id + 1}**) ${song.name} - \`${song.formattedDuration}\``).slice(0, 40).join("\n"))

    message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
  }

  if ([`3d`, `bassboost`, `echo`, `karaoke`, `nightcore`, `vaporwave`, `reverse`, `surround`, `earwax`].includes(command)) {
    if (!message.member.voice.channel) {
      message.channel.send("You are not in a voice channel.")
    }
    if (message.member.voice.channel) {
      let filter = distube.setFilter(message, command);
      const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#9966CC')
        .setTitle('Current Filter')
        .setDescription(filter || 'Off')

      message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
    }

  }
});

// Queue status template
const status = (queue) => `Volume: \`${queue.volume}%\` | Filter: \`${queue.filter || "Off"}\` | Loop: \`${queue.repeatMode ? queue.repeatMode == 2 ? "All Queue" : "This Song" : "Off"}\` | Autoplay: \`${queue.autoplay ? "On" : "Off"}\``;

// DisTube event listeners, more in the documentation page
distube
  .on("playSong", (message, queue, song) => {
    const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#9966CC')
      .setTitle('Currently Playing')
      .addFields({
        name: 'Song Name',
        value: song.name
      }, {
        name: 'Duration',
        value: song.formattedDuration,
        inline: true
      }, {
        name: 'Requested By',
        value: song.user,
        inline: true
      }, {
        name: 'Status',
        value: status(queue)
      }, )
    message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
  })

  .on("addSong", (message, queue, song) => message.channel.send(
    `Added ${song.name} - \`${song.formattedDuration}\` to the queue by ${song.user}`
  ))
  .on("playList", (message, queue, playlist, song) => message.channel.send(
    `Play \`${playlist.name}\` playlist (${playlist.songs.length} songs).\nRequested by: ${song.user}\nNow playing \`${song.name}\` - \`${song.formattedDuration}\`\n${status(queue)}`
  ))
  .on("addList", (message, queue, playlist) => message.channel.send(
    `Added \`${playlist.name}\` playlist (${playlist.songs.length} songs) to queue\n${status(queue)}`
  ))
  // DisTubeOptions.searchSongs = true
  .on("searchResult", (message, result) => {
    if (!message.member.guild.me.hasPermission(["CONNECT"])) return message.channel.send("I don't have the permissions to join the voice channel.")
    if (!message.member.guild.me.hasPermission(["SPEAK"])) return message.channel.send("I don't have the permissions to speak in the voice channel.")
    if (!message.member.guild.me.hasPermission(["SEND_MESSAGES"])) return console.log("I don't have the permissions to send messages.")
    let i = 0;
    const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#9966CC')
      .setTitle('Choose an option from below')
      .setDescription(`${result.map(song => `**${++i}**. ${song.name} - \`${song.formattedDuration}\``).join("\n")}\n\n*Enter anything else or wait 60 seconds to cancel*`)
    message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);

  })
  // DisTubeOptions.searchSongs = true
  .on("searchCancel", (message) => message.channel.send(`Searching canceled`))
  .on("error", (message, e) => {
    console.error(e)
    message.channel.send("An error encountered: " + e);
  });


client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.events = new Discord.Collection();
['command_handler', 'event_handler'].forEach(handler => {
  require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client, Discord);
})

client.once('ready', () => {
  client.user.setActivity("BlurryBot | b.help");
});



client.login("BOT_TOKEN");
```

**Error Message in Console**

```js
0|.        |     at Decoder.Transform._read (internal/streams/transform.js:205:10)
0|.        |     at Decoder.Transform._write (internal/streams/transform.js:193:12)
0|.        |     at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
0|.        |     at Decoder.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
0|.        | RuntimeError: memory access out of bounds
0|.        |     at <anonymous>:wasm-function[268]:0x2177a
0|.        |     at <anonymous>:wasm-function[267]:0x21732
0|.        |     at OpusScriptHandler$_decode [as _decode] (eval at Db (/root/BlurryBot/node_modules/opusscript/build/opusscript_native_wasm.js:1:1), <anonymous>:11:10)
0|.        |     at OpusScript.decode (/root/BlurryBot/node_modules/opusscript/index.js:80:28)
0|.        |     at Decoder._decode (/root/BlurryBot/node_modules/prism-media/src/opus/Opus.js:64:25)
0|.        |     at Decoder._transform (/root/BlurryBot/node_modules/prism-media/src/opus/Opus.js:189:20)
0|.        |     at Decoder.Transform._read (internal/streams/transform.js:205:10)
0|.        |     at Decoder.Transform._write (internal/streams/transform.js:193:12)
0|.        |     at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
0|.        |     at Decoder.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
```

**Error Message on Discord**

[image: Image Link]

I started receiving this error only when i shifted to digital ocean and it wasn't taking place before that.

Answer (score 0):

A few things at your disposal:

- Make sure your digital-ocean enviornment supports web assembly ( it probably does since you said it was working fine initially although if not consider requiring it like this:

```js
var encoder = new OpusScript(samplingRate, channels, OpusScript.Application.AUDIO, {
  wasm: false
});
```

- From what I judge ( by studying the error in the console ) it's mainly occuring in the opusscript dependency, you may want to switch to a different opus engine such as [@discordjs/opus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@discordjs/opus) with something such as ytdl-core / discord-player being it's alternatives, and completely abandoning distube as a dependency.
- Completely supress and ignore the errors if they don't exit your process and everything works fine.